# XML not parsing correctly for no clear reason

Tags: php, domdocument

I have my XML feed being created from an associative array.

Using new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

and it was working fine until I made some changes to the methods used to convert it from iso-8895-1 to UTF-8.

The character being flagged up is the letter R, but I have gone into the file via ftp and changed it manually (deleted and retyped r in case of any errors).

I changed it from `$summ = str_replace(chr(10),"",$summ);` to `$summ = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n"),"",$summ);` but as you can see below I have changed it back and nothing. I have also set DOMDocument to formatoutput=false, because it was previously set on true, but it all that did was move the problem to a different letter r, both are on the end of words?????

```
//$summ = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n"),"",$summ);
    $summ = str_replace(chr(10),"",$summ);
/*$v = str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$v);
$v = str_replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;","",$v);*/
$summ = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT",$summ);
$summ = str_replace("£","&pound;",$summ);
//$summ = htmlentities($summ, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$this->summary = addslashes($summ);
```

Comment: How does the character get flagged up? What does your XML look like? What is the error message that comes up?

Comment: Yes, let's have more on the error. None of the weird `replace` or `addslashes` stuff above is necessary or appropriate for generating XML from data. After using `iconv` to get UTF-8, all you should need to do is `htmlspecialchars()` each string being output into the XML template. You don't want `htmlentities()` as it will generate entity references like `&pound;` which do not exist in raw XML.

Comment: Without a description of what "being flagged up" means, or a reproducible example, there's not much anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the unclear question but I couldn't show code for reasons of the output beind sensitive.

Anyway, the problem was htmlentities, and htmlspecialchars caused the same problem, without them it works fine.